# Parslet: recognise anything but a given keyword

Tags: ruby, regex, parslet

I'm trying to write a Ruby/Parslet parser for Handlebars but I'm getting stuck with the `{{ else }}` keyword.
To explain brieflt for those who do not use Handlebars, an if/else is written this way:

```
{{#if my_condition}}
  show something
{{else}}
  show something else
{{/if}}
```

but it becomes tricky as the inlining and the helpers can use the same syntax, for example:

```
Name: {{ name }}
Address: {{ address }}
```

So I first made a rule to recognise the replacements:

```
rule(:identifier)  { match['a-zA-Z0-9_'].repeat(1) }
rule(:path)        { identifier >> (dot >> identifier).repeat }

rule(:replacement) { docurly >> space? >> path.as(:item) >> space? >> dccurly}
```

Which match anything like `{{name}}` or `{{people.name}}`.
The problem of course is that is also matches the `{{ else }}` block. Here is how I've written the rule to match an if/else block:

```
rule(:else_kw) {str('else')}
rule(:if_block) {
  docurly >>
  str('#if') >>
  space >>
  path.as(:condition) >>
  space? >>
  dccurly >>
  block.as(:if_body) >>
  (
    docurly >>
    else_kw >>
    dccurly >>
    block.as(:else_body)
  ).maybe >>
  docurly >>
  str('/if') >>
  dccurly
}
```

(note: docurly is `{{`, dccurly is `}}` and block can be more or less anything)

So my need now is to rewrite the `identifier``rule so it matches any word but not "else".

Thanks in advance,
Vincent

Comment: OMG! Let me escape first.. :(

Comment: Any of these answers useful?

Comment: Sadly I can't yet say, we've had some priority changes for the project and I did not get much time to work on this part of the project, so I had to keep the quick&dirty solution I found first (keeping the {{ else }} as any other identifier and treat it in the code (each block is splitted in two part if an {{ else }} identifier is found).
I hope I can try one of those solutions one day when I'll have time to work on this part of the project again ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this is to use the `absent?` lookahead modifier. `foo.absent?` will match if the atom or rule `foo` does *not* match at this point, and does so without consuming any input.

With this in hand, you could write the `identifier` rule as

```
rule(:identifier)
    { (else_kw >> dccurly).absent? >> match['a-zA-Z0-9_'].repeat(1) }
```

Comment: took a long time to get back to the parsley project, but your solution worked like a charm :)

Answer (score 0):

It depend on the syntax you are trying to match. If you were not inside an `{{if}}` `{{/if}}` pair should `{{else}}` be treated as a valid identifier or a syntax error? If you had a path with `a.else.b` should that be valid?

If `a.else.b` isn't valid you could do the following:

```
rule(:identifier)
    { (else_kw).absent? >> match['a-zA-Z0-9_'].repeat(1) | else_kw >> match['a-zA-Z0-9_'].repeat(1) }
```

which accepts all strings except "else", by saying "any string not starting with else, OR strings starting with else that have at least one more character".

Note: This makes me think "Why is `else` so special?" should we be excluding all keywords here?

If `a.else.b` is valid you can't exclude it at the identifier level. It's then more accurate to say your `path` can't be `"else"`.

If you said:

```
rule(:path)        { else_kw.absent? >> (identifier >> (dot >> identifier).repeat) }
```

This would rule out any identifier that started with 'else', e.g. "elsewise.option"

So.. the `absent?` needs to also match something to show your block has ended.

```
rule(:path)        { (else_kw >> dccurly).absent? >> (identifier >> (dot >> identifier).repeat) }
```

The problem here is that we are now coupling path to the idea that it ends with a `dccurly` which isn't strictly correct (and doesn't deal with whitespace). So "path" isn't the right place to put this stuff.

If we were trying to stop replacement from matching `else`, that would be easier.

```
rule(:replacement) { docurly >> space? >> (else_kw >> space? >> dccurly).absent? >> path.as(:item) >> space? >> dccurly}
```

That would prevent replacement matching `else`, but would allow `elsewise.something`, or `else.something`.

If you don't want "else.something" then you need something like this:

```
rule(:replacement) { docurly >> space? >> (else_kw >> (space | dccurly | dot)).absent? >> path.as(:item) >> space? >> dccurly}
```

so that "else " "else." and "else}}" are all prevented.